# How to store PHP defined constant (value) as a variable?

Tags: php, variables, constants

This is defined constant in config file.

```
define(BASE_URL, "http://example.com/lc-latest/");
```

I want to store in a variable for sending a confirmation email to complete the registration

```
$website=echo BASE_URL;
```

Comment: It's not right to write "= echo" ... you can simply use the standard assignment to assign global variable to a variable $website=BASE_URL;

Comment: yeah can you post your answer so that i can accept

Comment: never mind it's not a big deal, happy to help

Comment: sounds cool....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$website =  BASE_URL ;
<a href=" '.$website.'/confirm.php?accountid=' . $chk_number . '">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Actually the mail is in php tag only and `$chk_number` is coming